# handling db connection on daemonize threads

Tags: python, multithreading, psycopg2, daemons

I have a problem handling database connections in a daemon I've been working on, I first connect to my postgres database with:

```
try:
  psycopg2.apilevel = '2.0'
  psycopg2.threadsafety = 3
  cnx = psycopg2.connect( "host='192.168.10.36' dbname='db' user='vas' password='vas'")
  except Exception, e:
  print "Unable to connect to DB. Error [%s]" % ( e,)
  exit( )
```

after that I select all rows in the DB that are with status = 0:

```
try:
  cursor = cnx.cursor( cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
  cursor.execute( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 0")
  rows = cursor.fetchall( )
  cursor.close( )
except Exception, e:
  print "Error on sql query [%s]" % ( e,)
```

then if there are rows selected the program forks into:

```
while 1:
  try:
    psycopg2.apilevel = '2.0'
    psycopg2.threadsafety = 3
    cnx = psycopg2.connect( "host='192.168.10.36' dbname='sms' user='vas' password='vas'")
  except Exception, e:
    print "Unable to connect to DB. Error [%s]" % ( e,)
    exit( )

  if rows:
    daemonize( )
    for i in rows:
      try:
        global q, l
        q = Queue.Queue( max_threads)
        for i in rows:
          cursor = cnx.cursor( cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
          t = threading.Thread( target=sender, args=(i, cursor))
          t.setDaemon( True)
          t.start( )

          for i in rows:
            q.put( i)
            q.join( )
      except Exception, e:
        print "Se ha producido el siguente error [%s]" % ( e,)
        exit( )
  else:
    print "No rows where selected\n"
    time.sleep( 5)
```

My daemonize function looks like this:

```
def daemonize( ):
  try:
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid > 0:
      sys.exit(0)
  except OSError, e:
    print >>sys.stderr, "fork #1 failed: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strerror)
    sys.exit(1)

  os.chdir("/")
  os.umask(0)

  try:
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid > 0:
      sys.exit(0)
  except OSError, e:
    print >>sys.stderr, "fork #2 failed: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strerror)
    sys.exit(1)
```

threads target to sender function:

```
def sender( row, db):
  while 1:
  item = q.get( )
  if send_to( row['to'], row['text']):
    db.execute( "UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE id = %d" % sms['id'])
  else:
    print "UPDATE table SET status = 2 WHERE id = %d" % sms['id']
    db.execute( "UPDATE table SET status = 2 WHERE id = %d" % sms['id'])
  db.close( )
  q.task_done( )
```

`send_to` function just opens a url and return true or false on success

Since yesterday i keep getting these error and cant find my way thru:

```
UPDATE outbox SET status = 2 WHERE id = 36
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 477, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "sender.py", line 30, in sender
    db.execute( "UPDATE table SET status = 2 WHERE id = %d" % sms['id'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 88, in execute
    return _cursor.execute(self, query, vars, async)
OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

Comment: Too much code.  Can you cut this code down to the smallest thing that shows your error message?  Does a non-daemon version of this work?  Are your database credentials valid?  Did someone move the database server and not tell you?  If it used to work and doesn't work now, what did you change?

Answer (score 1):

Database handles don't survive across `fork()`.  You'll need to open a new database handle in each subprocess, ie after you call `daemonize()` call `psycopg2.connect`.

I've not used postgres but I know this to be definitely true for MySQL.